# Rails devise: create association on user sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

As a total Ruby noob i need to do a simple thing but doing it the ruby way is not clear for me.

What is want to do is the following:

I have a devise User model with a one to one association "Account"

In the devise registration view i want to add extra form fields for this account, and that is where i am stuck.

It seems i cannot add the account fields to the view

for example this will not work:

```
# address is a field of Account
<%= f.text_field :address %>
```

How can i bring the Account model into the scope? Or is there a way to do something like this

```
<%= f.text_field :account['address'] %>
```

I have really no clue how to add account into scope or how i can access the User assoc Account properly.

Thx for the help

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is what you need, I guess. Search for it and try to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :account` to able to add parameters from registration form.
Then whitelist these parameters by overriding devise method configure_permitted_parameters.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [account_attributes: [:address]])
end
```

You might need to change which parameters needs to be whitelisted.

Then in view,  you need to use   `fields_for` like

```
f.fields_for(:addresss) do |address_fields|
  <%= address_fields.text_field :address %>
end
```

Hopefully, this solves the problem. Try to search about nested attributes if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override devise `RegistrationsController` from there modify on `create` method to build `account` record when user successfully sign up

Comment: I totally agree, but i can't mangage to add extra fields in the form view that are none user related

Comment: To add extra fields you will have to use fields_for
For ex: `<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path('user'), :html => {:autocomplete => :off}, :remote => true ) do |f| %>
<%- user_detail = f.object.account || f.object.build_account %>
        <%= f.fields_for :account, account do |account_f| %>
<%= account_f.text_field :name%>
<% end %>
<% end %>`
(havent included everything that will go into the form)